# How do I successfully load a .TIFF image into MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a TIFF image that I am trying to read with the following code in MATLAB:

```
I = imread('example.tiff');

imshow(I)
```

However, when I try to do so, I get the following error:

```
Error using images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData (line 118)
Multi-plane image inputs must be RGB images of size MxNx3.

Error in images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams (line 30)
common_args.CData = validateCData(common_args.CData,image_type);

Error in images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs (line 79)
common_args = images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);

Error in imshow (line 253)
    images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs({'Parent','Border','Reduce'},preparsed_varargin{:});
```

When I save the same image in JPG format and use the same code to read it, I have no issues loading it into the image viewer. Can anyone diagnose the problem and offer workarounds? I just want to understand what is going on here. Is the file simply too big?

Comment: are you sure this is not a corrupted tiff file?

Comment: @FangQ I can't see how that would be... how can I verify that?

Comment: can you open it with any other image editor or viewer, like imageJ, gimp, paint etc?